# Two Relative CSS containers next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to develop a website where I need to have 2 CSS containers side by side at the same level. I.e. they both need to have top: 0px; However, whey they both have relative the first container is pushed down to where the second container content finishes.

How can I get these two containers to sit side by side both needing to be relative. I have been trying to figure it out for ages and google searches don't seem to provide with much help.

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 in order to build the website.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

**EDIT**
Below is the HTML Code

```
<div id="feedContainer">
    Latest Tech News<br /><
    The quick brown<br/> fox jumped over the lazy<br /><br />dogs back
 </div>
 <div id="bodyIndex">
     Hi I am a body<br />and i am a new line<br/>r />and i am a <strong>another new line</strong><br />I'm another<br /><br />woo!!<br /><br />
     <font size="+24">I am a large font<br /><br />Please don't move<br />the feed container
               </font>
        </div>
```

Below is the CSS Code

```
#bodyIndex
{
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 120px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   width: 660px;
   /*padding-bottom: 70px;*/
   /*height: 100%;*/
   /*top: 80px;   */
   /*background-color: #c8c8c8;*/
   background-color: #fff6d1;
   /*clear: both;*/
   clear:none;
   padding-bottom: 60px;
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto;
}


#feedContainer
{
    position:relative;
/*    top: 0px;*/
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 180px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    left: 800px;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border-left:thin solid #e0e0e0;
    clear: none;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of CSS containers]

In the image above where it says 'I am a body' and 'Latest Tech News' should be lined. The only way I can get them to line up is if I set one of them to absolute but I need both containers to be relative

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking for. Could you draw a picture?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you've got so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the containers into a `<ul>` and give the float left css property to the `<li>` within the unsorted list. Something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li style="float:left"> <!--Container here-->
   </li>
   <li style="float:left"> <!--Container here-->
   </li>
</ul>
```

That way the containers should appear side by side

Comment: Excellent thank you so much although I didn't put it inside <ul><li> tags I just did the float left for container 1 and float right for container 2

Comment: Just found a problem with this when I use float left and right it for some reasons stop the footer from working. Before the footer would stick to the bottom of the window until it reached the text of the body but now it doesn't it will overlap the body text if the screen is too small

Comment: I have also tried using the <ul><li> tags you suggested and it still stops the footing from working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand that position:relative means "relative to what would be my original position" and original box position may not be where you think it is.